# Difference between pkcs#11 and pkcs#12?

Tags: pkcs#11, pkcs#12

What is the difference between pkcs#11 and pkcs#12?
How do they work? How export pkcs#11 from e-token? 
How it use in java 1.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PKCS#12 is a container for certificates with associated private keys.
PKCS#11 is a protocol to work with hardware (usually). So you can't "export" PKCS#11. 
The rest of your question is way to broad to answer - try using Wikipedia as a starting point, then proceed to specifications.